# Output display Garbled(Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Click this link to see the image.

[The image on the right hand side is my code.It is about class in python.The image on the left hand side is my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zef2.png)

I wonder why my output become garbled.What should i do to make the output readable? I am new in Python...

Comment: Please put your code in the question as text, not an image!

The problem you're having is that you're printing *the method itself*. What you want to do is *call* the method, and print the result of the call: `print(rec.get_area())` (note the parentheses after `get_area`).

Comment: Thank you,i'll put the code as text in next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats intended behavior. You print just the methods and not the result of calling these methods.

Add brackets to the methods to print the result of calling them:

```
print(rec.get_area())
print(rec.calculate_cost())
```